# How do I open a word document in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ms-word

I want to open a Word document for the user to edit / print / other usual word tasks, but the Word document I try to open doesn't show up.

I googled and searched for different approaches, but all of them seems to link to 3 party packages that cost money.

Right now I tried this:

```
Application application = new Application();

        Document document = null;
        try
        {
            document = application.Documents.Open(filePath);
            application.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Fehler: " + e);
            if (document != null) document.Close();
            if (application != null) application.Quit();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (document != null) document.Close();
            if (application != null) application.Quit();
        }
```

I want a word document to open, but nothing is happening. 
The controller just links me to the next page, but no Word document is opening.

**Edit:**

I changed the way I'm doing it thanks to the information that I can't open office application server-side.

Now I have a simple Action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
                          "Word", //Text
                          "Viewer", //Action
                          "FirmaCreateEdit",
                          new Kunden.Models.View_Firma
                          {
                              Blz = item.Blz ....(other values)
                          },// routevalues
                          null
                      )
```

and write the data to the word document:

```
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=\"Firma.doc\"");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        Response.Write(firma.Blz);
        Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
    }
```

The writing works,(the data shows up) but there is also something like this in the document:

```
2674ÃŸPK          ! ß¤ÒlZ           [Content_Types].xml ¢  (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ´”ËnÂ0 E÷•ú ‘·Ubè¢ª* ‹>–-Ré { Vý’Ç¼þ¾  QU ‘
l"%3÷Þ3VÆƒÑÚšl   µw%ë =–“^i7+Ù×ä-d &á”0ÞAÉ6€l4¼½ L6 0#µÃ’ÍS
Oœ£œƒ Xø Ž*•V$z3 „ü 3à÷½Þ —Þ%p)Oµ  
^  
“²×5}nH" dÙsÓXg•L„`´ ‰ê|éÔŸ”|—PrÛƒs ðŽ  ?˜PWŽìt-t4Q+ÈÆ"¦wa©‹¯|T\y¹°¤,NÛ àôU¥%´úÚ-D/ ‘ÎÜš¢­X¡Ýžÿ(¦ ¼<EãÛ  )‘à  ;çN„ L?¯FñË¼ ¤¢Ü‰˜ ¸<FkÝ  ‘h ¡yöÏæØÚœŠ¤Îqô i£ã?ÆÞ¯l­Îià 1éÓ]›HÖgÏõm @ ÈæÛûmø   ÿÿ  PK          !  ‘ ·ï   N   
   _rels/.rels ¢  (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ¬’ÁjÃ0 
@ïƒýƒÑ½QÚÁ £N/cÐÛ Ù [IL ÛØj×þý<ØØ ]éaGËÒÓ“ÐzsœFuà”]ð –U
Š½  Öù^Ã[û¼x •…¼¥1xÖpâ 
›æöfýÊ#I)Êƒ‹Y ŠÏ  ‘øˆ˜ÍÀ å*Döå§
i")ÏÔc$³£žqU×÷˜~3 ™1ÕÖjH[{ª=E¾† ºÎ ~
f?±—3-ÂÞ²]ÄTê“¸2j)õ, l0/%œ‘b¬
 ð¼Ñêz£¿§Å‰…,   ¡   ‰/û|f\ ZþçŠæ ?6ï!Y´_áo œ]Aó   ÿÿ  PK          ! “£çmÎ   2
      word/document.xml¤–KoÛ0 
€ï ö¬ ß[ù '1š kÓ = 
(Öî<(²ü@¬$%nöëGÙqœÁ]á¸ G¢ÄO$E2º¹}cådO•. _:ÞµëL('")x¶t~½~¿š; m0Op)8]:ªÛÕ×/7Uœ ²c”›    ¸Ž+I–NnŒŒ Ò$§ 
ëkV %´HÍ5  
‰4- E•P ò]Ï­GR  Bµ†óî1ßcí qäm -Q¸ e

 É±2ô­cx C¦hæ}?   ú^¬ \ŒŠµª
GÀª i:ŽôŽsÑ8’ß'ÍÆ‘‚>i>ŽÔK'ÖOp!)‡ÅT(†
LU† VÛ¼ °Ä¦Ø ea 
Àt£ ƒ
¾ a h ,H.&Ì     -ƒ¤¥ˆ¥³S<>ê_ô­éq£üi5Ô ÿ •õ±9Ôž#EKˆ…à:/ä©ÂÙX ,æ-dÿ‘ {V¶û*é
,—ÿµ§u Ê 
8ÄücüYÙXþ1ÑsÜˆEœ4†˜ðï™­% 
²°;xThÎ‚ë
l -Àï "R 
Lé–ÑD ü Í3Ž¦—a¦-F¬XWê•Ì>—-JìdG+>G{êj¿²ÿÂ °ŽYw^  úsÆ¼äXBK`$~Ê¸PxS‚EC HƒI} ö
·2±Eç¬à©° ÉÁþJX c‰ ~‚ÛŽ  ë;Ï œZ
ÖXiø-¼_xž•Æð,I~. ×½s§÷þü$ZÓ ïJcW\ß]
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Remember: server side code runs on the server. ASP.NET is server side code (yes, even Razor! the server renders the Razor view). The code you have above will try to open Word on the server, which I'm sure isn't what you want.

Comment: That would be okay. The server should open a template where I insert some data so the User can print / download the file and so on. Would that be possible?

Comment: You *cannot* use Office in a server setting. You *will* need 3rd party components to do that. [more info](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing ah okay, thank you.

Comment: yes you are missing lot of understanding here... office and therefore .doc are tightly linked.. aka you cant not read a .doc file like you would a .txt file. you would need WORD to open it.... to get an instance of "word" capable class to allow you to read the file in its intended encoding... is why a 3rd party stuff is needed as it would be extremely difficult to write code to be able to do this..

Comment: If your use case is to change the content of a Word file server side, or create one, the basic Microsoft answer is [Open XML SDK 2.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk). **Do not use Office Automation server side it's not designed for that use case.**  
There are also various more user friendly packages on NuGet (DocX for exemple).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments I archieved what I want this way:

As before I call my Action with a object as parameter:

```
 @Html.ActionLink(
                          "Word", //Text
                          "Viewer", //Action
                          "FirmaCreateEdit",
                          new Kunden.Models.View_Firma
                          {
                              Blz = item.Blz,
                              Plz = item.Plz,
                              Ort = item.Ort
                          },// routevalues
                          null
                      )
```

Now, this Action is called:

```
public void Viewer(View_Firma firma)
        {
            string subfoldername = "App_Data";
            //Your fileName
            string filename = "test.docx";
            string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, subfoldername, filename);


            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true))
            {


                IDictionary<String, BookmarkStart> bookmarkMap =
                          new Dictionary<String, BookmarkStart>();

                foreach (BookmarkStart bookmarkStart in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<BookmarkStart>())
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(bookmarkStart.Name);
                    if (bookmarkStart.Name == "Plz")
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test");
                        FirmaCreateEditController.InsertIntoBookmark(bookmarkStart, firma.Plz);
                    }

                    if (bookmarkStart.Name == "Blz")
                    {
                        FirmaCreateEditController.InsertIntoBookmark(bookmarkStart, firma.Blz);
                    }


                }

            }

            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);

            if (file.Exists)
            {

                Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=\"Firma.doc\"");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
            }

        }
```

which iterates through all the bookmarks.
If I find a bookmark that I want to change, I call this function :

```
 public static void InsertIntoBookmark(BookmarkStart bookmarkStart, string text)
        {
            OpenXmlElement elem = bookmarkStart.NextSibling();

            while (elem != null && !(elem is BookmarkEnd))
            {
                OpenXmlElement nextElem = elem.NextSibling();
                elem.Remove();
                elem = nextElem;
            }

            bookmarkStart.Parent.InsertAfter<Run>(new Run(new Text(text)), bookmarkStart);
        }
```

which removes / sets the bookmark text.
Thanks for helping me out.

I hope this is the correct approach and I don't make a foul out of me again.